# Angular 6 AOT compilation error: Function calls are not supported in decorators

Tags: angular, typescript

I installed `ng-intercom` from (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-intercom) on my Angular Project, implemented that. Its working but in `ng serve` mode. But when I executed the command `ng build --prod` or `ng build --aot`. I get the error :

```
ERROR in Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'IntercomModule' was called.
```

It's working fine when i executed `ng build`.

Here is my `AppModule`:

```
import { IntercomModule } from 'ng-intercom';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [MyComponent],
  imports: [

    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,

    IntercomModule.forRoot({
      appId: 'my_id',
      updateOnRouterChange: true,
    }),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [MyComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Can you remove `IntercomModule` and try running `ng build --aot` ? and post its output?

Comment: `ng build --aot` works without `IntercomeModule`

Comment: Please take a look at this : https://github.com/CaliStyle/ng-intercom/issues/74

Comment: Ah I see! There seems to be no fix at the moment. Is there a temp workaround this? It is blocking me from doing a prod build :(

Comment: try `ng build --prod`

Comment: It gives the same error!

Comment: Then I think you'll need to wait until they push their resolved build.

Comment: @SoftwareNinja I'm having the exact same issue. I hope they fix it soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in version `7.0.0-beta.1`. Happy coding :)